# How to call methods of an external class from Activity?

Tags: android, sqlite

First let you know I am new in Android.

Trying to create multiple classes to handle database table operations. Created a database helper as follow:

```
 public class WSDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "wsemp";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;

        public WSDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
            .............
        }

        @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            ................
        }
    }
```

Created a class to handle database table operation:

```
public class CustomerBean {
    private WSDatabaseHelper database;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        database = new WSDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return false;
    }

public boolean insertObject(valObj) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(.......);
    }
}
```

But now I am not sure how I can call this insertObject function from my activity or session file. I tried by CustomerBean.isnertObject(obj) but it's asking to change the method to static.

Comment: make the method `static`

Comment: Whose `onCreate` method do you override in your `CustomerBean`?  Didn't you forget to extend the `Activity` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to call method in this situation

1. Create the object of the class and call method

   ```
     // Create object
    CustomerBean customerBean = new CustomerBean();

    // call the method
    customerBean.insertObject(<insert object here>);
   ```
2. Make the method static and call it from class name

   ```
   // In CustomerBean class
   public static boolean insertObject(valObj) {
      SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
      db.insert(.......);
   }

   //In WSDatabaseHelper class
   CustomerBean.insertObject(<object name here>);
   ```

On more thing to correct here is that in **CustomerBean** class you have written

```
  @Override
   public boolean onCreate() {
     database = new WSDatabaseHelper(getContext());
     return false;
   }
```

Which is not correct. onCreate() method of Activity class of Android and 
you can put **@Override** Annotation for this method only if your class is extending **Activity** class

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Add the `static` modifier to your method. Then you should be able to access it between classes.